# (Front Mission SNES) How can I beat Driscoll in mission 5 (Find Karen's Hospital)

Tags: front-mission

This question is about a mission in the original Front Mission game on SNES.

I know it is not required to complete the level (just killing all the normal wanzers is enough) but it seems doable, plus I heard he gives a ton of EXP and money which makes the next few levels easier.

The only strategy I have is having the team running around in circles and pepper him with missiles. But once the missiles run out I can't get in range to shoot at him without him killing me in the next turn.

So, is there any strategy to beat Driscoll in this mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking the question I replayed the game again and figured out. It's basically the same answer Chriss gives.
This is what I did.

- Equip everyone with a machine gun and a grenade launcher (Yes, even Keith, since the guy never learns any Melee skills other than Double).
- Disable enemy wanzers by destroying their arms. They don't run away, but instead stay close to Driscoll.
- Maneuver my team so that eventually one or more enemy wanzers will block Driscoll's path to my team. It is possible to use just one enemy wanzer at various chokepoints on the street. Also Driscoll should be the topmost target, so that when I press attack, Driscoll is the first target chosen.
- This is an exploit of the enemy AI. Driscoll's minions will charge at my team even when they cannot attack, and they can't think to get out of their boss' way.
- Press the "A" button a lot to attack Driscoll with the grenade launcher.
- Each attack, whether a hit or miss (GLs have 60% hit chance, and Driscoll can dodge too, so I missed a lot), gives 7 xp. Eventually someone will learn the Guide skill. Use that to target his arms. Also, sometimes the grenade launcher will have a "Critical", dealing 5-20 damage instead of the usual 1.
- After both of Driscoll's arms are destroyed (they give a meager 100xp each), move in and shoot him with machine guns (as they have better hit chance and shoot multiple bullets per turn).
- Once again, press the "A" button a lot :).
- After beating Driscoll with Lloyd, he gives about 1000xp and 7000 dollars. Plus, Lloyd learns Guide and Duel, and other team mates also level up their Short skill quite a bit, which makes the next few missions a lot easier.

Comment: mmm brings back a lot of fun memories of this game. Its a shame their last release (evolved) isn't a strategy game and sucks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to kill him . One button way !! you must have 3 wanzers that use granade l . Don't kill all enemy units . only destroy their limbs . They will move close to you and block Driscoll path. You will have 2 spaces of room to shot and they won't move. Just make sure to block their path. Than it's a long way to kill him. But he can't do anything.